# Integrate keycloak as a server authentication in django api

Tags: django, keycloak

I'm trying to connect Django with Keycloak  using mozilla-django-oidc
the problem is when i log in succefully using the keycloak login i got redirect to my localhost:8000 instead of my LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL that i have declared .

[my django settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4nkc.png)

[my redirect url declared in keycloak dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOlgq.png)

Comment: DO update your question replacing images of code with code snippet. Take a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Also, as per your image, it looks like the redirect url you have provided is localhost:8000. I assume that is why it is redirected there.